# From Love Story. How to play this measure showed in the picture with left hand?

Tags: fingering

[image]

How to play this measure with left hand? Also which finger for each note?
Thank you!

Comment: In asking how to play that measure, what exactly are you asking about? To me it seems straightforward. When you think about playing it, what specifically isn't clear to you about it?

Comment: I agree with Todd's comment: you have to be more specific what your problem is. If it's a generic "I don't know how it play it", you may need to step back a bit. As for fingering: 5-2-1-2-1 or 5-2-1-3-2 works for me. If about the bass note: since you'll be using the sustain pedal, you can leave the pinky off that note once you've moved to the next notes.

Comment: Which bar no. is this - I can't work out why the next bass note would be a G followed by an F#.

Comment: @Tim Probably a dominant chord above a tonic pedal in the bass.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty straightforward - pinky for the low G, pedal down immediately, to hold it. Then choice - either move l.h. to play the arp. starting on D with pinky again, then middle, index, thumb; or D with middle,thumb plays upper G, then over with whatever you fancy for the last two. The pedal stays down until the beginning of the next bar, and changes just after you hit that low G again, as the whole bar makes a G minor.

With fingering 'problems' like this, it's far better that the player works out his/her own. After all, they're the one playing it, and a little experimentation is good for progress and experience. After all, you could have two concert pianists with completely different ideas with such as this. Which might you choose?

Comment: The question still remains - what number bar is it?